# Deleted posts still stick there at /tools/flagged, is there anything we can do with those?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, flags

Deleted posts still stick there at /tools/flagged, is there anything we can do with those?

[image]

[image]

The questions was deleted by owners since an [hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547201/swf-problem-in-android) [ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546889/how-we-need-to-handle-other-person-in-team).

And voting to close gave me this message.

[image]